# Format conversion problem For mathjax

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

Take the code “[{f_i} = {x_i}\left[ {{c_i} + \ln \left( {\frac{{{x_i}}}{{\bar x}}} \right)} \right]]” for example，I could  get the proper formula displayed on the official website of "https://www.mathjax.org/#demo" ,but not on our website "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask".
Could you help me? or could you tell me some tool to convert latex to mathjax which can be used on our website?

Comment: Probably a better question on meta.

Comment: Replace the opening and closing [  ] by \$  \$ or \$\$  \$\$.

Comment: Thank u very much, when I replace "/[" or "/]" with "$",  the formal would perform well~

Comment: This ( https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35316/mathjax-out-of-date ) question's answer might help you: the version of MathJax that SE uses isn't all that current.